# Defining standard event handlers in SAP UI5 when not using MVC

Tags: sapui5

We are using SAP UI5 in SAP MII and if we use MVC it is not getting displayed in Portal, as portal in IE 9 makes rendering mode to Quirks whereas UI5 on MVC requires Standard mode in IE 9 to display the web page. We have also found that if we don't use MVC then UI5 web pages from portal are being displayed in Quirks mode itself. But the only problem we are facing on how to define the event handlers of UI5 standard events such as onAfterRendering. As there is no controller, the framework is not able to recognize the event handler when we define it in the usual way.

Any pointer on how to define standard event handler for UI5 in JS file shall be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Dipankar

Comment: Your question is somewhat complicated and I cannot parse it. What specific issue do you have, can you show the code that isn't working for you?

Comment: Apologies if I'd understood this wrongly. But what seems the case if on() events are not getting fired? Many cases firing certain conditions to react within your controllers, can be avoided by refiring DOM events as components, and in some cases, passing member instances. http://www.brianhadaway.com/javascriptmvc-anti-patterns/ Sorry, if this does not entirely help.

Comment: Hi DJ,  We are using UI5 but not following MVC pattern. We have one HTML files and multiple JS files where the controls and functions are defined. Everything is working fine except the standard event handler such as onAfterRendering. As we do not have a controller where and how can we define the event so that the framework understands it as the standard event handler? I tried in the usual way onAfterRendering:function(){

//event handler logic
}
but it is not working.

Thanks,
Dipankar

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why not using MVC and in particular a controller would enable the controls to work in quirks mode. I wouldn't expect the controls to render correctly etc, and not using the MVC pattern doesn't sound like a maintainable workaround.

There are a few blogs and SAP notes related to the quirks mode on the SCN, I've enclosed a few below.

[SAPUI5 on Portal](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/09/10/howto-run-sapui5-on-portal--portal-runtime-integration-quirks-co)

[Does SAPUI5 actually work in the SAP Portal?](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3495850)

Regards,

Jason

Comment: Hi, We are using both SAP EP and MII Portal. In EP we are having some WebDynpro iViews as well along with MII-UI5 pages so anyway the rendering has to be in Quirks mode, otherwise the WDP iviews won't get displayed. We found that not using the MVC objects it is being rendered in Quirks mode. But anyway we are using the View/Ctrl as JS files referring from the HTML file. Now the question is how to define the event handler of the standard events in UI5 such as onAfterRendering when not using a standard controller but a simple JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to run UI5 in Quirks Mode, why not run Web Dynpro applications in Standart Mode by implementing OSS Note 1911889 ? Then, you can put your UI5 and Web Dynpro content in Unified Framework Page on EP.